# Two nav elements in CSS

Tags: html, css, stylesheet, nav

**Problem:**

Writing common CSS code in order to be applied for two nav elements. I have searched all over Google and Stackoverflow without any success. It seems it's not common to use two nav elements while W3C allows it.

**HTML code:**

```
<!-- Global navigation -->
<nav role="main">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html" class="active">Startpage</a></li>
        <li><a href="cars.html">Cars</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.html">About us</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>

<!-- Local navigation -->
<nav role="sub">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="ferrari.html" class="pressed">Ferrari</a></li>
        <li><a href="bmw.html">BMW</a></li>
        <li><a href="volo.html">Volvo</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

**CSS code:**

How would I write CSS code in order for the two navigation elements to have the same layout, but different styling (color, font size, etc.)?

Comment: you haven't provided the css code.

Comment: you can create two separate css class for each nav and can assign the property as you want.

Comment: @kexxcream So, ultimately, you wanted the same layout for both navs, but everything else could be different?

Comment: That is correct, I'm sorry for not expressing this request clearly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```css
nav ul li {
    width:100px;
    display:inline-block;
    margin:5px;
    padding:5px;
    color:#333;
    text-align: center;
}
nav[role="main"] ul li {
    background-color:#aaa;
}
nav[role="sub"] ul li {
    background-color:#eee;
}
```

```html
 <!-- Global navigation -->
<nav role="main">
    <ul>
         <li><a href="index.html" class="active">Startpage</a></li>
         <li><a href="cars.html">Cars</a></li>
         <li><a href="about.html">About us</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>

<!-- Local navigation -->
<nav role="sub">
    <ul>
         <li><a href="ferrari.html" class="pressed">Ferrari</a></li>
         <li><a href="bmw.html">BMW</a></li>
         <li><a href="volo.html">Volvo</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what you mean by

> same appearance but different styling

You can use the `role` attribute as a CSS selector, as shown here:

```css
nav[role="main"], 
nav[role="sub"] {
  background: #222;
  color: #f40;
}

nav[role="main"] a, 
nav[role="sub"] a {
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<nav role="main">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="index.html" class="active">Startpage</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="cars.html">Cars</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="about.html">About us</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<!-- Local navigation -->
<nav role="sub">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="ferrari.html" class="pressed">Ferrari</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="bmw.html">BMW</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="volo.html">Volvo</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: I'm with you so far, but what if you start integrating ul, li and a css code? Don't you need to do it for both navs?

Comment: Still not entirely getting what you want. You want both navs to look exactly the same?

Comment: Yes, I want to know how you can assign two roles in CSS for the same code.

Comment: Like the updated snippet? You can have multiple selectors on one ruleset.